# I am trying to sort an array with a method similar to selection sort but my code is not working

Tags: arrays, sorting, selection-sort

I was trying to find an alternative for the selection sort algorithm and wrote this. It's not working and I don't know why.

```
int main()
    {
        int size;
        cin>>size;
    
        int arr[size];
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            cin>>arr[i];
        }
    
        int start=0;
        int getAdd;
    
        while(start<size)
        {
            int minEl = arr[start];
    
            for (int i =start; i < size; i++)
            {
                if(arr[i]<minEl)
                {   minEl=arr[i];
                    getAdd=i;
                }
            }
    
            swap( arr[start],arr[getAdd] );
            start=start+1;
    }
```

This code works just fine for a size equal to 6.
For a size greater than 6, it malfunctioning a little.
For a size less than 6 god knows what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you're not giving `getAdd` a new value every iteration of the `while` loop.

This means that the `for`-loop inside the `while` loop, this one:

```
for (int i =start; i < size; i++)
{
    if(arr[i]<minEl)
    {   minEl=arr[i];
        getAdd=i;
    }
}
```

if this loop doesn't find an element that is less than `minEl`, which will happen in those occasions where `arr[start]` is already the correct element, you will re-use the previous value given to `getAdd`, and then swap the correctly placed element in `arr[start]` with another previously correctly placed element in `arr[getAdd]`, where `getAdd < start`, messing up the sort order.

In the case where the first element is correctly placed, you will also probably use the uninitialized value for `getAdd`, which depending on your compiler and compiler settings might be an arbitrary "random" value.

This had nothing to do with 6 items by the way. My guess is that you tested it with 6 items or less that didn't have this situation. Any sized array that had no elements in the right spot already would probably be sorted correctly.

To fix this, move the declaration of `getAdd` into the `while` loop, and give it a suitable value:

```
int start=0;

while(start<size)
{
    int minEl = arr[start];
    int getAdd = start;

    for (int i =start; i < size; i++)
```

You can then also do a check before swapping:

```
if (start != getAdd)
    swap( arr[start],arr[getAdd] );
```

With the change to `getAdd`, you should find that your selection sort works as expected.

Comment: Thankyou Lasse, also I would like to know if the check before swapping is mandatory?

Comment: Not at all, it's a minor minor optimization.

Comment: Also, if my answer helped I would request that you click the Accept Answer green checkmark next to it. You can only accept one answer per question, but if a better answer comes along you can accept the new one instead.